# Login on Apps facebook

Tags: facebook, api, connection, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I try to use a SDK for an application on facebook but i really don't understand how work it..

The url example for my apps is apps.facebook.com/myapps
The url for the server is : www.myapps.com

The application is composed of two parts : 
- The first is open for all users
- Second need login for gives access to user's pictures, ...

I test if the user is logged with $facebook->getUser() and if he's not i use the $facebook->getLoginUrl().
But i think this URL is only used for website and not application because Facebook dont handle iframe (cf  screenshot with 2 headers) and redirection (redirect on www.myapps.com and not apps.facebook.com/myapps)

Screenshot :
http://www.kreatoo.com/rav/facebook.png

I don't understand how i must do ??

Thank you all  and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

The getLoginUrl function has one parameter, an array. You can specify the next and the cancel url.

```
  $params = array(
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'canvas' => 1,
    'next' => "http://apps.facebook.com/[YOUR_APP]/",
    'req_perms' => '[PERMISSIONS]'
);
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

The next specifies the url to go after successfull user authentication.

Comment: And do not use header() in canvas, use. `<script>top.document.location="...";</script>`

Comment: I have tried your code and it's the same bug =/
And I never call header(), it's facebook who launch an other facebook in this iframe